# Add a header in context menu

Tags: excel, vba

I want to insert a "header" in my context menu. By "header" I'm refering to the line, in the image below, that says "**Inklistringsalternativ:**".

[image: Inklistringsalternativ:]

This line cannot be clicked on. It simply looks like a header of some sort. So, what is it called? How do I reproduce this thing?

Comment: I don't believe you can add those. None of the controls that can be added using CustomUI look like that.

Answer (score 0):

[Customizing context menu](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg469862(v=office.14).aspx)

This link explains how to customize context menu.It consists of VBA code as well. Following these should pretty much help you.